# Linking 2 different html pages to 2 different css files

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website using dreamweaver, and i faced a problem with linking a css file to an html page.

In this site, the index.html is linked to style.css and it's working properly, but when i link the page Products.html to styleproducts.css, the html page appears not linked to any style page.
I have placed style.css and styleproducts.css in a folder named "css" and i placed Products.html in a folder named "pages".
Here's the link code written in Product.html:

```
<link href="css/styleproducts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is wrong try out this

```
<link href="../css/styleproducts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Your Product.html is in another folder. So you need to leave the folder with "../" than enter "css"